# VSTO Add-In for MS Word getting disabled automatically all the time

Tags: vsto, add-in, office-addins

I've developed a VSTO Add-In for MS Word. When I'm installing the Add-In into client's machines, every time I've to enable the Add-In Manually.

I've signed my add-in using a Certificate.

Can anybody help me why the add-in is getting disabled again and again.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Right after installing the add-in I'd suggest checking the `LoadBehavior` key value (before MS Word is started). By default, this entry is set to 3, which specifies that the VSTO Add-in is loaded at startup. Read more about such keys in the [Registry entries for VSTO Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/registry-entries-for-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2019) article.

Microsoft Office applications can disable VSTO Add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your VSTO Add-in, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your VSTO Add-in.

Hard disabling can occur when a VSTO Add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the `Startup` event handler in your VSTO Add-in is executing.

Soft disabling can occur when a VSTO Add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable a VSTO Add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the `Startup` event handler is executing.

When you re-enable a soft-disabled VSTO Add-in, the application immediately attempts to load the VSTO Add-in. If the problem that initially caused the application to soft disable the VSTO Add-in has not been fixed, the application will soft disable the VSTO Add-in again. Read more about that in the [How to: Re-enable a VSTO Add-in that has been disabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-re-enable-a-vsto-add-in-that-has-been-disabled?view=vs-2019) article.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue.

MS Office disables the Add-ins automatically, if it crashes. In my case the exception was thrown from the starting point i.e.
    ThisAddIn_Startup

Office was not able to instantiate the the add-in, because there was no document open and was causing this exception.

**This was the exception: This command is not available because no document is open.**

> To fix this error, I wrote following lines which opens a blank MS Word Document, if any document is not open:

```
 if (Application.Documents.Count == 0)
                this.Application.Documents.Add();
```